# Connect to 192.168.0.1:8080 [/192.168.0.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect in node js when resolving com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

hello i am trying to run app in react native but when loading dependencies i.e  com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.  i get an error saying :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'new'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
  >   Connect to 192.168.0.1:8080 [/192.168.0.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
  >   Connect to 192.168.0.1:8080 [/192.168.0.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

my build.gradle class is configured to what most solutions are offering

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

but still i cant get a solution to load the com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
i dont know if the error originates from the 
Connect to 192.168.0.1:8080 [/192.168.0.1] failed: Connection timed out: connect part .
anybody with a solution please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution finally. This error comes due to proxy. apparently i had installed gradle with previous settings which used proxy servers. To solve this. go to local gradle installation ie for windows
    C:/users/username/.gradle 
search for settings.gradle and remove all proxies 
or change to the proxies you are using.